Probability measure on partition theorem
Probability measure in $\mathbb{R}^1$: Continuous function $f$ that is positive everywhere $\ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f dx =1$ (total area under the curve equals 1). For visualization see here.
Measure of a subset $S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^1$: Integral over that subset. There is a way to split measure into two equal parts(1/2 and 1/2)
Probability measure in $\mathbb{R}^2$: Continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}$ that is positive everywhere and $\ \iint_\mathbb{R^2}f d\textbf{x}d\textbf{y}=1.$ For visualization see here.
Equipartition theorem (Ceder 1964): Every probability measure $f$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be divided into 6 equal parts by 3 concurrent lines.

Proof: For every direction $\vec{v}$ there exists a unique line $\ell$ parallel to $\vec{v}$ that partitions $f$ into two equal parts. $\ell$ varies continuously with  $\vec{v}.$ Given $\vec{v}$ and given a point $x\in \ell(\vec{v})$ there exist 4 unique rays from $\ell$, two on each side, that partition $f$ into 6 equal parts.
As $x$ moves forwards, the rays rotate backwards. For visualization see here.
There is a unique point $x^*$ for which $r_1,r_4$ form a straight line. Let $\alpha$ be the clockwise angle from $r_2$ to $r_3$.$\alpha
=\alpha(\vec{v})$ varies continuously with $\vec{v}.$
When $\vec{v}$ turns $180°$, $x^∗$ returns to the same place,
$$r_1↔r_4, 
r_2↔r_3, 
α↔360°-α.$$
There must exist an intermediate value of $\vec{v}$ for which $\alpha(\vec{v})=180°.$ For visualization see here.
Q.E.D

My question is how can Prove that every probability measure in $\mathbb{R^2}$ can be divided into 6 equal parts by 3 lines, 2 of which are parallel? For visualization see here.We can use the above Equipartition theorem.

Please write in English, not sentence fragments. What about your probability measures in the sentences containing no predicates? (They are certainly not the usual definitions of probability measures on ℝ or ℝ^2.)

You can argue using the intermediate value theorm.
Here is a sketch:
Claim 1. For each $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, there is one and only one way to divide the plane into three equal-measure regions using two parallel lines $\ell_1(\theta)$ (the bottom one) and $\ell_2(\theta)$ (the top one) with angle $\theta$.
We denote the obtained three regions by $Q_T$ (top), $Q_M$ (middle), and $Q_B$ (bottom).
Claim 2. For every $\theta\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$, there is one and only one line $\ell_3(\theta)$ that divides each of the two regions $Q_T$ and $Q_B$ into equal-measure parts.
The line $\ell_3$ divides $Q_M$ into two parts, which we denote by $Q_{ML}$ (the left one) and $Q_{MR}$ (the right one).
Claim 3. The triplet $\big(\ell_1(\theta),\ell_2(\theta),\ell_3(\theta)\big)$ is continuous in $\theta$.
Claim 4. We can extend $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3$ to the closed interval $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ in a continuous fashion.  At $\theta=-\pi/2$ and $\theta=\pi/2$, we get the same three lines and the same six regions, but $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ switch places and so do $Q_{ML}$ and $Q_{MR}$.
Namely, at $\theta=-\pi/2$:

$\ell_1$ is the left line and $\ell_2$ the right one,
$Q_{ML}$ is the top middle region and $Q_{MR}$ is the bottom middle region,

while at $\theta=\pi/2$, it is the other way around.

Now, let
\begin{align*}
   f(\theta):=\mu\big(Q_{MR}(\theta)\big) - \mu\big(Q_{ML}(\theta)\big)
\end{align*}
where $\mu(A)$ denotes the measure of a region $A$.
Note that $f(\theta)$ is continuous on $[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ with $f(-\pi/2)=-f(\pi/2)$ (because $Q_{ML}$ and $Q_{MR}$ switch places).  Therefore, by the intermediate value theorem, there must exist a point $\theta_0\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$ at which $f(\theta_0)=0$.
At $\theta=\theta_0$, the three lines $\ell_1,\ell_2,\ell_3$ divide the plane into six equal-mass regions.
